# Paths not working to handsontable JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter, handsontable

[image]

This is probably something really easy but I'm stumped and can't get the paths working in my codeigniter project. I'm trying to install the latest handsontable (.12.2) . Following the instructions (https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/tree/master/dist) I have the following html in the head of my page:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
      <base href="<?=base_url();?>">


      <!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>      

<script src="handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css">
```

The file structure is in the screenshot.

When I try to load the page I see the following in the console:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/b1/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/b1/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/b1/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess in  `<base href="<?=base_url();?>">` you should do  `<base href="<?php echo base_url();?>">`. That should work.

Comment: Ok. Whats your .htaccess configuration? Do your site has example.com/index.php/controller type url? If yes, then your url file url is looking for something like http://localhost/b1/index.php/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css You can check this one too if you haven't checked yet. @user61629

Comment: I don't have an htaccess file here. I've worked around it by using the github repo as a CDN    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.css"> ,     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
I'm upvoting your answer, but it didn't help in this case.